# Gramática: "tengo miedo que" y "tengo miedo y creer que"

Tags: gramática

Se dice que:

> 1. tengo miedo de que + verbo subjuntivo
>      e.g. Pero tuve miedo que no pudiera o pudiese dormir bien...
> 2. tengo miedo y pensar/creer que + verbo conditional
>      e.g. Pero tuve miedo y creía que no podría dormir bien....

Why if I use "pensar/creer", the conditional verb will be followed but not subjuntivo? Isn't "pensar/creer" imply a doubt?

Comment: `Pero tenía miedo y creía que no podría dormir bien` or `Pero tuve miedo y creí que no podría dormir bien`

Comment: Also, more colloquial: `Pero tuve miedo y creí que no iba a poder dormir bien`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about *pensar que* or *creer que*, it is about something called *Transporte de Negación*. Basically, when the negation moves from the subordinate frase to the main one, the subordinate verb should be transformed to the subjuntive form.

Example:

> Creía que no podría dormir bien  (conditional verb + < 'no' + conditional verb >)
>
> No creía que pudiese dormir bien ('no' + conditional verb + < subjunctive verb >)

Source:

[Gramática Del Subjuntivo](http://books.google.es/books?id=tY-yTIewV8UC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=subjuntivo%20%20negaci%C3%B3n&source=bl&ots=4VP83ELb1W&sig=sZ5owKvK7FWjS56rkZkF_6I4jpw&hl=es&sa=X&ei=sRkgUJ_xGeLF0QW01oDQCQ&ved=0CG0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=subjuntivo%20%20negaci%C3%B3n&f=false), page 88 after examples (4) (5) (6). I didn't read all the book, maybe a different explanation is provided somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Pensar and creer are normally followed by the subjunctive only in the negative.

Thus:

> - Pienso que lo saben.
> - No pienso que lo sepan.
> - ¿Piensas que lo saben?

Comment: why in positive we use conditional but in negative we use subjunctive? Why when we use "de que" subjuntive will be used?